# Android: Resize image width and height in dip

Tags: android, image, bitmap, resize

I am creating an app that downloads an image from a url, save them on the device and after must load them into a ImageView with a fixed size.
For the download and the saving of the file i've no problem but when i try to set the image in the ImageView i have a fatal error, because the image is to large for my ImageView (i think...).

this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ff9f9f"
android:layout_margin="2dip"
android:padding="2dip">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff9f9f"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:padding="2dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notizieTitolo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/immagineNotizie"
        android:text="Titolo"
        android:textColor="#6b71f1"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_margin="2dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notizieSottoTitolo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/immagineNotizie"
        android:text="SottoTitolo"
        android:textSize="15dip" 
        android:layout_margin="2dip"/>

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/icona"
        android:id="@+id/immagineNotizie"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_margin="2dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Is a simple layout with a ImageView, one TextView to the right of the ImageView and a TextView under all

The important is the ImageView with and height. Are set to 100dip (if i count the 2dip for the margin).

this th code of the class with the image saved in a Bitmap.

```
public class Notizia {
    String url;
    String titolo;
    String sottoTitolo;
    String nomeImmaginSalvata;
    Bitmap immagine;

public Notizia(String tit, String sottoTit, Bitmap imm, String lk){
    titolo = tit;
    sottoTitolo = sottoTit;
    immagine = imm;
    url = lk;
    nomeImmaginSalvata = nomeImmSalvata;
}
}
```

In this case I will use the image immediately after the download without saving it to disk, because it isn't essential to save.

This is the code for create a dynamic layout using the xml layout

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout insertPoint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_content);
        List views = new ArrayList();

        Iterator<Notizia> it = (Dati.listaNotizie).iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Notizia not = it.next();
            View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_notizie, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notizieTitolo);
            Bitmap yourBitmap = not.getImmagine();
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 10, 10, true);
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notizieSottoTitolo);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immagineNotizie);
            img.setImageBitmap(resized);
            textView.setText(not.getTitolo());
            textView1.setText(not.getSottoTitolo());
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            views.add(view);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++)
            insertPoint.addView((View) views.get(i));
    }
```

My question is: how to resize the image width and height in 100dip (or 98)?

I've try the

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, width, heigh, true);
```

but nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert from dp to px and since `createScaledBitmap` uses px. Use this funcions:

```
private float pxFromDp(float dp)
{
    return dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}

private float dpFromPx(float px)
{
    return px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dont scale the image ....

remove this..

```
  Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 10, 10, true);
```

I think then it will work...

Answer (score 0):

For Resizing ImageView use following class.

ResizableImageView.java

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Drawable d = getDrawable();

    if (d != null) {
        // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right
        // edges
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width* (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight()/     (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        // int height=10;
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
}
```

And ImageView with following:
replace com.demo.demoproject with your package name.

```
<com.demo.demoproject.ResizableImageView
    android:id="@+id/immagineNotizie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icona"/>
```

For loading large images i suggest go for Aquery methods where you can downsample large images with desired resolution images.
     https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading